# Transfer for the group of coinvariants

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $M$ be a $G$-module,
that is, an abelian group written additively on which $G$ acts:
$$ (g,m)\mapsto g m.$$
We consider the *group of coinvariants*
$$ M_G:=G/\langle g m -m\ |\ g\in G,\,m\in M\rangle. $$
Let $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup of finite index.
I am trying to understand the *transfer map*
$ M_G\to M_H$.

Choose a section $s\colon H\backslash G\to G$ of the projection $G\to H\backslash G$ onto the quotient space $H\backslash G$.
Consider the homomorphism
$$ N\colon M\to M,\quad\ m\mapsto \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s(x) m.$$
This homomorphism  $N$ induces  a homomorphism
$$
N_*\colon M\to M_H,
$$
which is clearly independent of the choice of the section $s$.

> **Question.**
> Why does the homomorphism $N_*$ descend to a homomorphism
> $$ N_{**}\colon M_G\to M_H\ ?$$

In other words, for $m\in M$ and $g\in G$, why is
$$ \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s(x)\cdot( g m -m)$$
a linear combination of elements of the form $h m'-m'$ for $h\in H$ and $m'\in M$?

Comment: What is $H \backslash G$ for you? (I think there are two competing conventions.)

Comment: Corrected. I mean the quotient space $H\backslash G$ (the set of right cosets of $H$ in $G$).

Comment: Crossposted in MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/461006/4149 with an additional question about possible references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the concrete version of your question:

> In other words, for $m\in M$ and $g\in G$, why is
> $$ \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s(x)\cdot( g m -m)$$
> a linear combination of elements of the form $h m'-m'$ for $h\in H$ and $m'\in M$?

In this, I shall assume that $H\backslash G$ is the set of right cosets of $H$ in $G$. That is, an element of $H\backslash G$ has the form $Hg$ for some $g \in G$.

Now to your question: Let $m\in M$ and $g\in G$. Let $I$ denote the $\mathbb Z$-linear span of the elements of the form $h m'-m'$ for $h\in H$ and $m'\in M$. We must show that $$ \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot\left( g m -m\right) \in I .$$

To this purpose, I consider the map
\begin{align}
\phi : H\backslash G &\to H\backslash G, \\
x &\mapsto xg \qquad \left(\text{that is, } Hy \mapsto Hyg\right),
\end{align}
which is obviously bijective. For each $x \in H \setminus G$, we have
\begin{align}
s\left(x\right) gm - s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right) m \in I .
\label{eq.darij1.1}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
[*Proof:* Let $x \in H \setminus G$. Set $y := s\left(x\right)$. Then, $x = Hy$, and thus $\phi\left(x\right) = \phi\left(Hy\right) = Hyg$ by the definition of $\phi$. Hence, $s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right) = s\left(Hyg\right) \in Hyg$, so that $s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right) = hyg$ for some $h \in H$. Considering this $h$, we now find
\begin{align}
\underbrace{s\left(x\right)}_{=y} gm - \underbrace{s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right)}_{=hyg} m = ygm - hygm \in I
\end{align}
(since $h\in H$ and $ygm \in M$). This proves \eqref{eq.darij1.1}.]

Now, we can substitute $\phi\left(x\right)$ for $x$ in the sum $\sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot m$ (since $\phi$ is a bijection). We thus obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot m
= \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right)\cdot m .
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot\left( g m -m\right) \\
&= \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot gm
- \underbrace{\sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot m}_{=\sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right)\cdot m} \\
&= \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(x\right)\cdot gm
- \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right)\cdot m \\
&= \sum_{x\in H\backslash G} \underbrace{\left(s\left(x\right) gm - s\left(\phi\left(x\right)\right) m\right)}_{\in I \ \text{ (by \eqref{eq.darij1.1})}} \\
&\in I \qquad \left(\text{since $I$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module}\right).
\end{align*}
Qed.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, Darij!